# QPushbutton settext Problem in QT?

Tags: qt

I am facing problem while Setting text in QPushbuuton.
I set the text on a button , but it never appears.

I have written a Custom Class for mousepress,mouserelease event for QPushbutton.

I Promote my QPushbutton to this class.

My code looks like :

//Customclass.h

enum ButtonState
{
    Normal,
    MouseOver,
    Pushed
};

```
class CustomButtonStates : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit CustomButtonStates(QWidget *parent = 0,const QString &normal = "", const QString &active = "",QString strText = "");
    virtual ~CustomButtonStates();
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent  *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent  *event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);



private:

    QString m_PixmapNormal;
    QString m_PixmapActive;
    QString m_strText;
    bool m_bPressed;
    ButtonState state;

public:
    QImage *NormalImage;
    QImage *MouseOverImage;
    QImage *PushedImage;




};
```

// .cpp

```
CustomButtonStates::CustomButtonStates(QWidget *parent,const QString &normal, const QString &active,QString strText) :
    QPushButton(parent)
{

    m_PixmapNormal = normal ;
    m_PixmapActive = active ;
    m_strText = strText ;
    state = Normal;



}


void CustomButtonStates::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(event);
    state = Pushed;    
    this->repaint();

}

void CustomButtonStates::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    state = Normal;
    emit clicked();
    this->repaint();

}

void CustomButtonStates::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QImage *pic = NULL;

    NormalImage = new QImage(m_PixmapNormal);
    PushedImage = new QImage(m_PixmapActive);
    switch (state)
    {
    case Normal:
        pic = NormalImage;
        break;
    case MouseOver:
        pic = MouseOverImage;
        break;
    case Pushed:
        pic = PushedImage;
        break;
    default:
        pic = NormalImage;
        break;
    }

    painter.drawImage(0, 0, *pic);
}

CustomButtonStates::~CustomButtonStates()
{
    delete NormalImage;
    delete MouseOverImage;
    delete PushedImage;
}
```

In my Page :

```
 CustomButtonStates *btnMain ;
btnMain = new CustomButtonStates(this,":/Sampl1.png",":/Sample2.png","Users");
    btnMain->setText("Users");
    btnMain->setGeometry(QRect(3,6,65,33));

    connect(btnMain,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(on_btnUsers_clicked()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any of the stuff painted in the `QPushButton` except the text and *your* data (images/pixmaps), I suggest you can go a little deeper an directly inherits of `QAbstractButton` instead.

In *your* button you will add a text member (plus accesors `setText(const QString&...)` and `text()`) then re-implement the paint event to draw your image and at last text above this background with one of the `drawText()` method of the `QPainter`.

`paintEvent` will look like this :

```
void YourButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    //hereadd some logic to determine witch pixmap goes background
    QPixmap* selectedPixmap ...
    painter.drawPixmap( rect(), *selectedPixmap);
    //here add some logic to set painter pen and brush 
    //according to button status (enabled/checked/...)
    painter.drawText( rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, text());
}
```

If you need fancier stuff like word wrapping, or Qt 'css' style to be applied to you text I suggest to use directly a `QLabel` and forward text accessor to this `QLabel`. In this case do not forget to re-implement `resizeEvent` to set correctly the overlay label on the top of your button rectangle any time it is changing.

Answer (score 1):

You should paint text manually in your overriden paintEvent method.
But mush easier - as OrcunC suggested, use Stylesheet instead.

```
QPushButton pb;
pb.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Users/nav_on.png);");
```

Comment: But i have create a custom class to set image on mouse press and release , if i have 100 pages i need to do it 110 times...how to paint text manually ?

Answer (score 0):

try calling QPushButton::paintevent(event) first in your custom paintevent then apply your custom QImage.

Comment: I have added QPushButton::paintevent(event) as last line of my custom paint event now what image i am assigning to button that is not coming ?

Comment: try calling the paint event FIRST then you apply your image. My mistake. If that doesn't work, you will have to paint the text by yourself, after painting the QImage (should really be a QPixmap btw)

Comment: Why don't you use style sheet for your push button ? It is much more easier than doing your own painting.

Comment: @OrcunC: Can you suggest how to do that ?

Comment: See http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton. Do something similar. Google also gives many examples.