# in Qt Creator, How to set background image on QLabel of specific Class

Tags: qt, coding-style, button, stylesheet, qlabel

I created a new class clickable label which inherits from QLabel and acts as a sort of 
"push button".

I would like to use background images as the button it self. This way I could also change the background image for various states (disabled, clicked, released).

How can I either specify a style sheet to only change the attributes for that label, or change a property/attribute of Qlabel somehow? (I know the style sheet would be background-image url(xxx) but it would change all my buttons to that image in my custom class)

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582245/qpushbutton-settext-problem-in-qt), I think that making *your* button on to of `QAbstractButton` is a decent solution

Answer (score 0):

You can target a specific widget by assigning a style sheet just to that particular widget by calling `setStyleSheet(const QString & styleSheet)` on it.

If you want to use a stylesheet further up the widget hierarcy, or at the application level, you can target a particular widget by using a css selector like this:

```
QWidget[objectName="myObject"]
```

You would need to make sure that the widget in question has its ojbect name set using `setObjectName("myObject")`.